# Hazelcast spring-boot entity cache

Tags: hazelcast, spring-cache

We currently utilize Hazelcast in a non-clustered environment alongside Spring Cache Abstraction. However, we now intend to transition into a clustered environment and require our cache to be replicated across multiple machines. The challenge we're facing is that our cached entities involve one-to-many relationships, resulting in slow performance.

For instance, consider the following example:

```
class Student {
     int id;
     String name;
     @OneToMany(lazy)
     List<Lecture> lectures;
}

@Cacheable(name=Cache)
List<Student> search(String namePrefix) {
}
```

During the serialization process, all lazy fields are being serialized. Since our entities have deep relationships and sometimes even circular references, this leads to a significant amount of data being transmitted over the network in the clustering setup.

Is there a configuration setting in Hazelcast that allows us to bypass the serialization of lazy fields?

Comment: Is [HibernateProxy.writeReplace()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy.html#writeReplace()) being called ? You might need to inspect the serialized bytes to confirm